# applying AND operation on variables in java

Tags: java, variables, hex, decimal, bit-manipulation

I want to do an "AND" operation between a and b (both decimal). the value of b is determined inside the code. As a result, if I write sth like:

```
String g= Integer.toHexString(b);
int k=a & g;
```

I get error, because it should be sth like:

```
int k=a & 0xFF;
```

somehow 0x should be before the hex value, and at the same time it can't be of type String. I did not find any example in Internet for the cases that the second operand can be a variable. Should I write manually a for loop to apply the AND operation bit by bit, or there is a straight forward solution for it?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If b is already an integer, your code should just be:

`int k = a & b;`

A number is a number is a number.  The human representations of `0xFF` vs `255` makes no difference at all to the & operator.  There is no such thing as a "Hex Integer" vs a "Decimal Integer" to the computer,  it's just a value.  The different ways of writing it are on the human end.

Comment: @KingsIndian do not understand what you mean by "to do" that.  It's just a figure of speech.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
int k = a & b;
```

There's no need to convert an `int` to a hexadecimal before applying the `&` operator. In fact, that is an error, because the value returned by `toHexString()` is a `String`, and the `&` operator works for integers only.

Answer (score 1):

When you write the hex literal 0xFF in your java code, it's the same as writing integer literal 255.

Hence there's no point converting your integer to string, doing a & b is sufficient. The hex notation is just how you specify your literal